# CKAN - Add Tags at Resources

Tags: tags, ckan

i'm trying to add tags to a Resource. For now, it is handling it as a simple string, and i want to be saved as a list of tags, not a string with tags separated by commas.

Comment: In CKAN, resources don't carry tags, but their containing datasets do. How do you specify the tags (web UI, API, etc.)?

Comment: I have modified CKAN, we need it more like a collection of documents than datasets, I added a tags in resources extras, the way its done in datasets, but they save it as a string, if i modify database and make it a list, it works as i expect, my question is what is the code that uplads resource_extras in the database?

Comment: If you're using a modified version of CKAN then this depends a lot on your exact modifications and what you're trying to achieve. Please update the question and tell us what you modified, how you enter and retrieve the tags, what exactly you're expecting and what you're getting instead.